# Grails + How to add months to a Date

Tags: grails

In Grails, is there a simple way to add/subtract months to/from a date?

We have methods like dateObj.add(10), which would add 10 days to dateObj. So my question is is there a way to add months.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `TimeCategory` class provides a DSL for time manipulation:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

use (TimeCategory) {
    twoMonthsFromNow = new Date() + 2.month
}
```

The documentation for `TimeCategory` can be found [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can try :

```
d = new GregorianCalendar() 
d.setTime(new Date()) 
d.add(Calendar.MONTH,5) 
d.getTime()
```

Comment: Thanks Adrien, that did work. But i was searching for a one liner. Something like `dateObj.add(10)`, which off-course adds 10 days to the dateObj.

Comment: So maybe you can use TimeCategory. This is an example :
https://gist.github.com/gfrison/812501

Comment: Yes, on the basis of syntax, that was exactly what i was looking for. But i guess that's not included in Grails bundle, caz am geting a _unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.TimeCategory_ error. Thanks Adrien

Comment: But if you use only dateObj.add(Calendar.Month, 5), you add five month to your date and the syntax is in one line.
In my sample of code, I give you a complete example of using Date but only the third line add month to the date.